# PowerShell Error connect to instance google cloud

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform

i tried to connect to my instance in google cloud using powershell app

this is code i enter into powersheell

```
$ gcloud compute ssh |
    >> ubuntugui |
    >> --zone asia-southeast2-a |
    >> --project eminent-booking-325201 |
    >> --ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
```

and this error showed, i tried \ but its still same

```
At line:3 char:3
+ --zone asia-southeast2-a |
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:3 char:1
+ --zone asia-southeast2-a |
+ ~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:3 char:3
+ --zone asia-southeast2-a |
+   ~~~~
Unexpected token 'zone' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:3
+ --project eminent-booking-325201 |
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:4 char:1
+ --project eminent-booking-325201 |
+ ~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:4 char:3
+ --project eminent-booking-325201 |
+   ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'project' in expression or statement.
At line:5 char:3
+ --ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:5 char:1
+ --ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
+ ~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:5 char:3
+ --ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
+   ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'ssh-flag' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

For the PowerShell prompt, then use the **backtick** character `

```
gcloud compute ssh ubuntugui `
--zone asia-southeast2-a `
--project eminent-booking-325201 `
--ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
```

Extra information for other operating systems:

For the **bash** shell use the **backslash** character \

```
gcloud compute ssh ubuntugui \
--zone asia-southeast2-a \
--project eminent-booking-325201 \
--ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
```

For Windows command prompt the **caret** character ^

```
gcloud compute ssh ubuntugui ^
--zone asia-southeast2-a ^
--project eminent-booking-325201 ^
--ssh-flag "-L 5901:localhost:5901"
```

Comment: Good information, but note that the OP is clearly using PowerShell, as evidenced by the error messages.